# Square-Connect 400 error - which characters are not valid?

Tags: square-connect

I'm receiving a 400 on what looks to be valid json (passes JSONLint validation). Square connect does not like the description field:

```
{
"requests": [
    {
        "method": "POST",
        "relative_path": "/v1/me/items",
        "access_token": "xxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "body": {
            "name": "9001 Donald Duck",
            "description": "’a’",
            "abbreviation": "test",
            "visibility": "PRIVATE",
            "available_online": false,
            "variations": [
                {
                    "name": "credit card payment",
                    "pricing_type": "FIXED_PRICING",
                    "price_money": {
                        "currency_code": "USD",
                        "amount": "-8735"
                    },
                    "sku": "7fa314q7_B9001_0",
                    "track_inventory": true
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

}

The same problem occurs for these characters as well: `“ ”`

When I try to key those characters in using the dashboard,  I get "We’re sorry, but something went wrong." So clearly these characters should be avoided.

Is there a list of invalid characters?  Also,  it would be helpful if you posted back the portion of the json object that caused the failure.  It seems silly to waste time trying to figure out the cause when it is known on Square's end,  no?

Comment: Here are some more invalid characters:  – (a dash, not hypen)  and opening/closing curly quotes ( ‘ ’ ).  While coding by trail and error is a lot of fun,  what would it take to get a list of invalid characters?

Answer (score 0):

I'm receving a 400 sometimes,too.request is renew and parameter is below.

```
  def refresh_access_token!
    ....
    begin
      #renew api
      response = oauth_connection.post SQUARE_RENEW_URL do |req|
        req.headers['Authorization'] = "Client #{SQUARE_CLIENT_SECRET}"
        req.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        req_body = req.body = "{ \"access_token\": \"xxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx\" }"
      end
    ....
  end

  def oauth_connection
    @oauth_connection ||= Faraday.new(SQUARE_CONNECT_URL) do |conn|
      conn.request :url_encoded
      conn.request :json
      conn.response :json, :content_type => /\bjson$/
      conn.adapter Faraday.default_adapter
    end
  end
```